# My laptop wont display the fan is on but the screen wont turn on

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

My laptop is not working. All of a sudden i turned on the laptop and the screen is black. Ive tried to hook it up too my 32" flatscreen tv to my laptop with a VGA cable and i set the input to pc, but it didnt work. All it said was signal cannot be displayed. PLEASE HELP-Paul Bradley

Comment: Make and model of laptop?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Right now your quesion is like: "My car does not turn on, I tried turning the key but it is still off". Be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

take off battery press power button for 3 mins
to drain power from computer then plug in laptop turn on laptop with charger plugged in and press power to see test result. if device screen does not 
boot repeat the process. 'thank you'

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

Does the computer display the screen on the T.V

If not then try `fn` and `f8` depending on your computer it may vary, the symbol looks like a rectangle / Projector screen

This has worked for me when having some trouble

Make sure to try do this on the built-in computer keyboard not an usb wired/wireless keyboard

Some computers let you press the project button (or any other f button) without pressing `fn`